# Python randomly generated IP address as string

Tags: python, ip-address

In Python, what should I do if I want to generate a random string in the form of an IP address?

For example: `"10.0.1.1"`, `"10.0.3.14"`, `"172.23.35.1"` and so on.

Could someone give me some help?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> import socket
>>> import struct
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(1, 0xffffffff)))
'197.38.59.143'
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(1, 0xffffffff)))
'228.237.175.64'
```

**NOTE** This could generate IPs like `0.0.0.0`, `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: If I want to get an IP address V6, what should I do ? Thank you !

Comment: What if I want to generate an IP in a specific range (e.g. between 1.2.4.8 and 8.4.2.1) ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein `for n in range(0x01020408, 0x08040201): ... socket.inet_ntoa(...)`

Comment: @changzhi see my answer below for IPv6

Comment: You don't need to call inet_ntoa if binary IPs works for you, the binary format is much smaller than a string format in size(always 4 bytes for IPv4 and 16 bytes for IPv6) which makes it a safe choice for sending/receiving over stream sockets

Comment: This could actually not generate 0.0.0.0 as randint starts at 1, right? Similarly one can simply use 0xfffffffe to avoid 255.255.255.255, correct?

Comment: @MappaM, You're right. Alternatively, you can use `random.randrange(1, 0xffffffff)` which exclude `0xffffffff`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange

Answer (score 39):

If you just want a string:

```
import random

ip = ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255) 
                        for _ in range(4))))
```

Comment: You can take out the map and just do `".".join(str(randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(4))`

Answer (score 16):

```
from faker import Faker  
faker = Faker()  
ip_addr = faker.ipv4()
```

Reference: [Fake-Apache-Log-Generator](https://github.com/kiritbasu/Fake-Apache-Log-Generator/blob/master/apache-fake-log-gen.py)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative way to generate a random string in the form of an IP address is:

```
>>> ip = '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(*__import__('random').sample(range(0,255),4))
>>> ip
'45.162.105.102'
```

Answer (score 8):

You also have Python's [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress) available to you, useful more broadly for creating, manipulating and operating on IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and networks:

```
import ipaddress
import random

MAX_IPV4 = ipaddress.IPv4Address._ALL_ONES  # 2 ** 32 - 1
MAX_IPV6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address._ALL_ONES  # 2 ** 128 - 1


def random_ipv4():
    return  ipaddress.IPv4Address._string_from_ip_int(
        random.randint(0, MAX_IPV4)
    )

def random_ipv6():
    return ipaddress.IPv6Address._string_from_ip_int(
        random.randint(0, MAX_IPV6)
    )
```

Examples:

```
>>> random.seed(444)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> random_ipv4()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'79.19.184.109'
>>> random_ipv4()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'3.99.136.189'
>>> random_ipv4()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'124.4.25.53'
>>> random_ipv6()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'4fb7:270d:8ba9:c1ed:7124:317:e6be:81f2'
>>> random_ipv6()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'fe02:b348:9465:dc65:6998:6627:1300:29c9'
>>> random_ipv6()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'74a:dd88:1ff2:bfe3:1f3:81ad:debd:db88'
```

Comment: I have a potentially stupid question that I couldn't clarify from the documentation or Google - Why does ipaddress.IPv4Address._ALL_ONES / ipaddress.IPv6Address._ALL_ONES  give us the total number of IP addresses minus 1? Is one address reserved as a broadcast address? Thanks

Comment: Don't forget about zero.  That's the first valid IP address @mmTmmR

Comment: Haha doh, thanks, think I stared at my screen for too long and got myself confused! Cheers, your solution was exactly what I was after!

Comment: Elsewhere in my code, I have used np.random.randint(). So as to be consistent, for above I tried to swap out random.randint(0, MAX_IPV4/6) for np.random.randint(0, (MAX_IPV4/6 +1)). (As np.random.randint() is exclusive of the upper value, I added one to the value of MAX_IPV4/MAX_IPV6 for this version.) For the IPV4 version this works as per your answer above, however when I try to do the IPV6 version I get the following error: "ValueError: high is out of bounds for int64". Do you have any thoughts on this error? Do I need to cast my IPV6 result to a different datatype? Thanks

Comment: @mmTmmR `np.random.randint()` can only go as high as `2 ** 64 - 1`, a 64-bit integer, while `ipaddress.IPv6Address._ALL_ONES` is 128 bits.  If you only need _one_ random address, use just [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html); NumPy is designed for arrays.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [123]: '.'.join('%s'%random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(4))
Out[123]: '45.204.56.200'

In [124]: '.'.join('%s'%random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(4))
Out[124]: '7.112.222.205'
```

Comment: Underrated answer. Nice way to generate IPs, without external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too obvious but if you need random IPs within a range you can use this:

```
import random

for x in xrange(1,100):
  ip = "192.168."
  ip += ".".join(map(str, (random.randint(0, 255) 
                          for _ in range(2))))

  print ip
```

Answer (score 1):

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers/faker.providers.internet.html

```
import faker
fake = Factory.create()
ip_addr = fake.ipv4(network=False)
```

lib has a lot of other useful options to fake data.

Answer (score 1):

### Faster: Mimesis

If you're looking for speed, try out [Mimesis](https://mimesis.readthedocs.io/)

```
from mimesis import Internet 
random_ip = Internet().ip_v4()
```

[image]

### IP with valid CIDR: Faker

If you're looking to generate a random IP adress with a valid CIDR, try out [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

```
from faker import Faker  
random_valid_ip = Faker().ipv4()
```

[image]

For more details on why Faker takes longer, see this [issue](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/issues/845).

Answer (score 1):

If trying to only generate private IP addresses based off user space (192.168.xxx.xxx, 172.16.xxx.xxx-172.31.255.255, and 10.xxx.xxx.xxx)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801633/python-program-to-generate-the-private-ip-addresses/68320748#68320748) post gives good answers

If you are trying to generate ANYTHING else, which *can* be considered public, use this (my code is based off the post above):

```
import random
def randomPublicIPaddress():
    '''
    oct 1 - cant be 10
    oct 2 - if oct1 == 192
                cant be 168
            if oct1 == 172
                cant be 16-31
    oct 3 - can be anything
    oct 4 - can be anything
    '''
    oct1 = random.choice([i for i in range(0,255) if i not in [10,127]])
    if oct1 == 192:
        oct2 = random.choice([i for i in range(0,255) if i not in [168]])
    elif oct1 == 172:
        oct2 = random.choice([i for i in range(0,255) if i not in range(16,31)])
    else:
        oct2 = random.randint(0,255)
    oct3 = random.randint(0,255)
    oct4 = random.randint(0,255)

    return ".".join(map(str,([oct1,oct2,oct3,oct4])))
```

Word of warning, there are many other ip address ranges that are considered "private" make sure to review the list on [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
from faker import Factory

fake_generator = Factory.create()
print(fake_generator.ipv4())
```

Be sure to pip install prior to trying to run the above!

```
pip install Faker
```

Check out the package documentation: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

Here is a [link directly to the ipv4 method docs](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.internet.html#faker.providers.internet.Provider.ipv4)