# Python Program to generate the Private IP Addresses

Tags: python

Below given program is to generate N number of private IP addresses randomly.

If x1 = 172,x2 value should be from 16 to 31...But it generate the value from 0 to 255... Can someone please have a look and let me know what could be the error?

**Code:**

```
import random

n = int(raw_input("How many IP addresses need to be generated \n"))

x1 = random.choice(["10","172","192"])


for i in range (0,n):

    if (x1 == 10 ):

        x2 = random.randint(0,255)

        x3 = random.randint(0,255)

        x4 = random.randint(0,255)

        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))



    elif (x1 == 172):

        x2 = random.randint(16,31)

        x3 = random.randint(0,255)

        x4 = random.randint(0,255)

        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))


    else:

        x2 = random.randint(0,255)

        x3 = random.randint(0,255)

        x4 = random.randint(0,255)

        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))
```

Comment: if you are working with ip addresses it may be worth considering this module: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are checking `int with string`

**i.e)**

```
1=="1"
Out[10]: False
```

**Modification:**

```
import random
n = int(raw_input("How many IP addresses need to be generated \n"))
x1 = random.choice(["172","192","10"])    
for i in range (0,n):
    if (int(x1) == 10 ):
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    elif (int(x1) == 172):
        x2 = random.randint(16,31)            
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    else:    
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))
```

**edit:**

```
import random
n = int(raw_input("How many IP addresses need to be generated \n"))
x1 = random.choice([172,192,10])    
for i in range (0,n):
    if (int(x1) == 10 ):
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    elif (int(x1) == 172):
        x2 = random.randint(16,31)            
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    else:    
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))
```

**edit2:**

Since `if and else` or doing the same thing you can merge them as `else`

```
import random
n = int(raw_input("How many IP addresses need to be generated \n"))
x1 = random.choice([172,192,10])    
for i in range (0,n):
    if (int(x1) == 172):
        x2 = random.randint(16,31)            
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    else:    
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))
```

**output:**

```
How many IP addresses need to be generated 
20
10.88.254.205
10.205.49.201
10.67.147.81
10.10.75.63
10.136.166.197
10.241.237.2
10.33.204.114
10.10.190.132
10.11.72.207
10.24.178.32
10.215.156.125
10.75.79.15
10.47.159.174
10.177.12.191
10.96.189.105
10.141.216.118
10.99.138.176
10.92.138.176
10.81.147.16
10.246.147.4
```

**edit3:**

And I personally think that the `x1 that is ip first segment should change  randomly when looping`

**Therefore this edit code:**

```
import random
n = int(raw_input("How many IP addresses need to be generated \n"))

for i in range (0,n):
    x1 = random.choice([172,192,10]) #moved inside loop
    if (int(x1) == 172):
        x2 = random.randint(16,31)            
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))

    else:    
        x2 = random.randint(0,255)
        x3 = random.randint(0,255)        
        x4 = random.randint(0,255)
        print ".".join(map(str,([x1,x2,x3,x4])))
```

**output:**

```
How many IP addresses need to be generated 
20
192.178.231.68
192.253.233.190
192.114.158.193
192.196.30.127
172.22.44.3
172.23.180.6
10.69.55.105
10.105.63.195
172.21.0.195
192.83.125.135
10.36.196.137
10.8.251.102
192.38.130.4
172.22.21.131
10.204.243.231
192.136.121.203
172.30.89.149
192.40.178.100
192.155.127.75
172.23.97.228
```

Comment: @vignesh.it should be  x1 = random.choice([10,172,192]) not  x1 = random.choice(["10","172","192"])  ?

Comment: @Maverick yes you could do like that to

Comment: ,when i think it started working when i gave x1 = random.choice([10,172,192])

Comment: @Maverick yes it would since you are checking `int against int it would work` :)

Comment: @Maverick see answer now :)

Comment: @Maverick happy to help

Answer (score 1):

When x1 is set you are using quotes making it a string.  Remove the quotes and it will be a numeric.  This is important later when you compare it to a numeric value.

```
x1 = random.choice([10,172,192])
```

Then the comparison elif (x1 == 172) will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with this code?

```
from random import randint
def randomPrivateIPaddress():
    network_type = randint(0, 2)
    if network_type == 0:
        return "10.%d.%d.%d" % (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
    elif network_type == 1:
        return "172.%d.%d.%d" % (randint(16, 31), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
    else:
        return "192.168.%d.%d" % (randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
```

Then, you can use those string with ipaddress module.

Answer (score 0):

Many here have provided good solutions for taking care of well known private IP addresses. By "well known" I am referring to:

```
192.168.xxx.xxx
172.16.xxx.xxx - 172.16.31.255.255
10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

However. I do want to clarify there are many other "reserved" ip addresses ranges that are not used for the public use based off [IANA documentation](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). These can all be considered being in the "private" space.
Most notably are localhost ranges (127.xxx.xxx.xxx) and Multicast addresses (240.0.0.0/4), which are widely used today.